# Contractible topological groups

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, topological-groups

Does there exist a Hausdorff topological group which is contractible and of finite covering dimension but which is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ for some $n$?

Comment: By the Yamabe theorem / Hilbert's 5th problem this reduces to the question of if such a group can have "small subgroups".  I imagine the answer to that is no, and so your question would have the answer no as well.  But off the top of my head I don't see a proof.

Comment: @Lars: you probably assume Hausdorff (otherwise the indiscrete topology on any finite group is contractible).

Comment: @Ryan: you seem to implicitly assume the group locally compact. In this case the answer is indeed negative: if $G$ is a connected LC-group and $K$ a compact subgroup then $G/K$ is contractible iff it is homeomorphic to a Euclidean space. Reference: http://arxiv.org/abs/1104.1820 (Arch. der Math 2012)

Comment: @YvesCornulier : Yes, I did mean to assume Hausdorff.  I'll add that assumption.  Thank you very much for the reference in the case where the group is locally compact!

Comment: I think that I have an example (I still need to check its dimension).

Answer (score 17):

If a topological group is contractible, then it is locally contractible (using the group operation produce a contraction which does not move the unit of the group). By a classical result of [A. Gleason, R. Palais, On a class of transformation groups, Amer. J. Math.
79 (1957), 631–648], a locally path-connected finite-dimensional topological group is a Lie group and being contractible, is homeomorphic to an Euclidean space.

Comment: Irrational line on the torus with induced topology is contractible, but not locally contractible. Or am I missing something?

Comment: No, it is not contractible: the contraction along the line is discontinuous in the topology induced from the torus.

Comment: Thank you, Taras. What is a reference for 'contractible implies locally contractible' in this setting?

Comment: I do not know. This is just a simple exercise: if $h:[0,1]\times G\to G$ is a contraction of a topological group $G$ with $h(\{1\}\times G)=\{1_G\}$, then the homotopy $l:[0,1]\times G\to G$ defined by $l(t,x)=h(t,x)\cdot h(t,1_G)^{-1}$ does not move the unit $1_G$ of the group and hence witnesses that $G$ is locally contractible at $1_G$.

Comment: @TarasBanakh, however, the standard definition of a space locally contractible at point $p$ is different: for every neighborhood of $p$ there is a neighborhood of $p$ contained in the given one, and contractible inside that larger neighborhood to $p$.

Comment: @Wlod AA But for topological groups "your" local contractibility is equivalent to "mine".

Comment: @TarasBanakh why is a contractible Lie group homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: @freakish This follows from the Cartan-Iwasawa-Malcev theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_compact_subgroup) which implies that every connected Lie group $G$ is homeomorphic to $M\times \mathbb R^n$ for some maximal compact subgroup $M$ of $G$ and some $n$. The contractibility og $G$ implies the contractibility of the compact group $M$, and contractible compact groups are singletons, see e.g. https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF01238544.pdf